# How many RDD Partitions and Slaves on a Standalone custer

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

This may be a basic question but I am little bit confused.

I have created a standalone cluster with one master and one slave both on 4 core ubuntu machine. I intend to run a spark streaming application on this. Now the questions that I have is :

Q1.what will be the number of partitions of the DStream that will be created ?

Q2. Also, Can I create two slaves on one machine ? If yes how ?

Thanks

Comment: A1. Benchmark is a way to start, no secret recipe for that! A2. Yes you can. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to start two slaves by running sbin/start-slave.sh , but this command only starts one and failes on the second time

Comment: The number of partitions will be dependent of the consumer, batch interval and block interval, or # of kafka partitions in the case of the direct Kafka consumer. See http://virdata.com/tuning-spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you have already installed your spark properly.

#### Start the Spark master:

To start the Spark master on your localhost:

```
$> ./sbin/start-master.sh
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /home/eliasah/utils/spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/../logs/spark-eliasah-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-eliasah-XPS-L501X.out
```

Once you have started your master, you can check the Spark UI on your http://localhost:8080/ . You'll see the following :

[image: Spark Master]

#### Starting slave workers

The spark master requires passwordless ssh login to its slaves, and since we're building a standalone Spark cluster, we'll need a passwordless localhost connection.

If your private key has a password, you'll need to generate a new key and copy its public part to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. (This part will be long to write in an answer, so I'll skip it. I believe you are big enough to figure that out)

Here is where it gets fun :

You create spark-env.sh file using the provided template:

```
cp ./conf/spark-env.sh.template ./conf/spark-env.sh
```

You need to specify the number of workers at the end of the spark-env.sh file

```
echo "export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=4" >> ./conf/spark-env.sh
```

All you need to do now is to start the spark-slave**s** :

```
./sbin/start-slaves.sh
localhost: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/eliasah/utils/spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/../logs/spark-eliasah-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-eliasah-XPS-L501X.out
localhost: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/eliasah/utils/spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/../logs/spark-eliasah-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-2-eliasah-XPS-L501X.out
localhost: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/eliasah/utils/spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/../logs/spark-eliasah-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-3-eliasah-XPS-L501X.out
localhost: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/eliasah/utils/spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/../logs/spark-eliasah-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-4-eliasah-XPS-L501X.out
```

You can also check the Spark UI :

[image: Spark Slaves]

I think this answer your second question.

As for the first question, like I said, you need to benchmark the numbers of partition considering your hardware configuration and performance measure. No secret recipes for that!

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer because it does help me in an second part of question. However I am not sure for part 1,  As per my understanding DStream is a RDD and I wanted to know if in the above scenario the RDD will have 4 partitions ( 1 per worker ) or some other number?

Comment: A DStream isn't an RDD. It's sequence of RDDs. What scenario are you talking about?